# Upload multiple images with node in s3 map problem

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm struggling finding a solution to upload two files to s3. I can upload one file with multer and I have learnt how to do it, but when I try to do a map inside all files in the formdata and upload each file, I push into an array each location URL which is the one I save in my database. Then I try to print each url but for my surprise they are print inside the if statement but not when I save it in the database outside the if. Could it be for an asychronous problem?.
Thanks.

```
tournamentsCtrl.createTournament = async (req, res) => {
    var files_upload = []
    if (req.files) {
        aws.config.setPromisesDependency();
        aws.config.update({
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            //region: process.env.REGION
        });
        const s3 = new aws.S3();
        req.files.map((item) => {
            var params = {
                ACL: 'public-read',
                Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
                Body: fs.createReadStream(item.path),
                Key: `tournament_img/${uuidv4()/* +req.file.originalname */}`
            };

            await s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error occured while trying to upload to S3 bucket', err);
                }
                if (data) {
                    fs.unlinkSync(item.path); // Empty temp folder
                    const locationUrl = data.Location;
                    files_upload.push(locationUrl);
                    console.log(files_upload)
                }
            });
        });
    }
    console.log(files_upload)
    const new_data = { ...JSON.parse(req.body.values), img_source: files_upload[0], info_url: files_upload[1] }
    console.log(new_data)
    const newUser = new Tournaments(new_data);
    newUser
        .save()
        .then(user => {
            res.json({ message: 'User created successfully', user });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error occured while trying to save to DB');
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) it does not return a promise so you should not call await on it. The default map method is not compatible with async code in this form. You need to either use [async.map](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map) or wrap the async code in a promise like

```
return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
...
    if (data) {
      fs.unlinkSync(item.path);
      resolve(data.location);
    }

}
```

Your other code has some issues as well. A map function should return a value. If you dont want to return anything you should use foreach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to solve it but it's been impossible. Could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad place to ask for code advice but something like the following

```
function uploadFile(s3, element) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let folder;
        if (element.fieldname.includes('img')) {
            folder = 'club_images'
        } else if (element.fieldname.inlcudes('poster')) {
            folder = 'poster_tournament'
        } else {
            folder = 'info_tournament'
        }
        const params = {
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
            Body: fs.createReadStream(element.path),
            Key: `${folder + '/' + uuidv4() + element.fieldname}`
        };
        s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            if (data) {
                return fs.unlink(element.path, err=> {
                    if(err) {
                        console.error("Failed to unlink file", element.path);
                    }
                    return resolve({[element.fieldname]: data.Location});
                }); // Empty temp folder
            }
            return resolve();

        });
    })
}

tournamentsCtrl.createTournament = async (req, res) => {
    aws.config.setPromisesDependency();
    aws.config.update({
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        //region: process.env.REGION
    });
    const s3 = new aws.S3();

    try {
        const uploadData = await Promise.all(req.files.map(element => uploadFile(s3, element)));
        const returnData = Object.assign({}, ...uploadData);
        console.log(Object.assign(JSON.parse(req.body.values), returnData));
    } catch(e) {
        console.error('Failed to upload file', e);
        return res.sendStatus(500);
    }

    const newUser = new Tournaments(Object.assign(JSON.parse(req.body.values), files_upload));
    console.log(newUser)
    try {
        const user = await newUser.save()
        res.json({message: 'User created successfully', user});
    } catch(e) {
        console.error('Error occured while trying to save to DB');
        return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
};
```